# Do JavaScript files get loaded asynchronously in ASP .NET?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asynchronous

So I have been reading about  tags and how they get loaded. It seems that unless JavaScript is dynamically injected it is loaded synchronously.

SOURCE: http://www.sitepoint.com/a-detailed-breakdown-of-the-script-tag/

That being said I was wondering whether ASP .NET "dynamically injects" JavaScript. Are there specific instances where ASP .NET would load JavaScript asynchronously?

Comment: ASP.NET is a server-side language so it can't have an effect on what the browser does. So if you write `Response.Write("<script src=\"\"></script>");` in ASP.NET it will function the same as if you were just using plain old HTML. If you're worried about async, use [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/)

Comment: it's just html... scripts are loaded synchronously, unless you explicitly have `<script defer src=...>` or `<script async src=-...>`

Answer (score 2):

> It seems that unless JavaScript is dynamically injected it is loaded synchronously.

That's not true. The reference you link to even talks about the `defer` and `async` attributes.

> That being said I was wondering whether ASP .NET "dynamically injects" JavaScript.

ASP.NET is a server side technology. The reference you link to demonstrates dynamic injection of script elements: It is done using *client side* code.

So no, at least not directly. You can write ASP.NET to generate JS that dynamically injects other scripts. You can write ASP.NET to generate HTML that includes script elements directly.

Answer (score 0):

> Do JavaScript files get loaded asynchronously in ASP .NET?

No, they don't.

However, you can use the `async` [keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) like any website - it isn't part of ASP.NET.